# dc.js - data table using jquery data-table plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, dc.js

I'm using `dc.js` to create charts and data table.

I wanted to add some pagination styles and search option in the  table.

**jQuery Data table script :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#data-table').DataTable();
})
```

problem is - i get all the jquery data table options displayed like search box, number of entries. But none of them work.

Some one please help.

Found this [**post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21113513/dcjs-reorder-datatable-by-column). But nothing useful.

Comment: Gordon Woodhull published his solution to this problem : https://github.com/dc-js/dc.datatables.js related to this issue https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/966

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I like to use DynaTable for this - http://www.dynatable.com/

1) Define your table html:

```
<table id="dc-data-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th data-dynatable-column="client_name">Client</th>
        <th data-dynatable-column="project_name">Project</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
 </table>
```

2) Hook in dynatable with your preferred options and the crossfilter dimension:

```
         var dynatable = $('#dc-data-table').dynatable({
                features: {
                    pushState: false
                },
                dataset: {
                    records: tableDimension.top(Infinity),
                    perPageDefault: 50,
                    perPageOptions: [50, 100, 200, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000 ,10000]
                }
            }).data('dynatable');
```

3) Write a method to refresh the table - dc.events helps to limit the number of times this is called on brush changes:

```
            function RefreshTable() {
                dc.events.trigger(function () {
                    dynatable.settings.dataset.originalRecords = tableDimension.top(Infinity);
                    dynatable.process();
                });
            };
```

4) hook this method into each charts filter event:

```
            for (var i = 0; i < dc.chartRegistry.list().length; i++) {
                var chartI = dc.chartRegistry.list()[i];
                chartI.on("filtered", RefreshTable);
            }
```

5) Call Refresh table once to display the current data:

```
            RefreshTable();
```

6) Render the DC charts:

```
            dc.renderAll();
```

Here is a jsfiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/djmartin_umich/5jweT/2/

Note that in this fiddle I used the group rather than the dimension to feed the dynatable data.

Comment: What's the difference between jquery dataTables and dynaTables?

Comment: They are both plugins for jquery.I like dynatable because the syntax is nicer and it's easier to change how things get rendered.  Check out http://www.dynatable.com/

Answer (score 6):

Since I prefer to use DataTables, I adapted DJ Martin's solution like so:

Set table html:

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped" id="dc-data-table">
  <thead>
  <tr class="header">
    <th>Day</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Set your DataTables options:

```
var dataTableOptions = {
  "lengthMenu": [ [10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"] ],
  "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
    var api = this.api(), data ;

    var total = ndx.groupAll().reduceSum(function (d) { return d.amount }).value() ;
    // Update footer
    $( api.column( 1 ).footer() ).html(
      currencyFormat(total)
    ) ;
  },
  "order": [[1, 'desc']],
  "dom": 'T<"clear-l"l><"clear-l"i><"clear-r"f><"clear-r"p>t',
  "tableTools": {
    "sSwfPath": "copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
  },
  columnDefs: [{
      targets: 0,
      data: function (d) {
        return d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%d')(d.first_request) ;
      }
    }, {
      targets: 1,
      data: function (d) {
        return currencyFormat(d.amount) ;
      }
    }
  ]
} ;
```

Create DataTables instance:

```
var datatable = $('#dc-data-table').dataTable(dataTableOptions) ;
```

Create RefreshTable function and attach to charts:

```
function RefreshTable() {
  dc.events.trigger(function () {
    datatable.api()
      .clear()
      .rows.add( tableDimension.top(Infinity) )
      .draw() ;
  });
}
for (var i = 0; i < dc.chartRegistry.list().length; i++) {
  var chartI = dc.chartRegistry.list()[i];
  chartI.on("filtered", RefreshTable);
}
RefreshTable() ;
```

Call RefreshTable() once to load initial data, and render all charts:

```
RefreshTable() ;
dc.renderAll() ;
```