# dc js - Create Multiple Column Dimension

Tags: javascript, d3.js, crossfilter, dc.js

I'm trying to summarize the data table using `dc.js` and I'm using `dynaTable` plugin for for pagination and other options.

Normally in the `dc.js` data table we get the entire data displayed in the data. But I'm trying to summarize the data like a pivot table and display it on the web and when the selection happens the data table needs to change.

I've done it by creating a `dimension` and `group` and i passed that group to `dynaTable`. And it's working fine.

Suppose I have 5 columns of data. I can create a dimension on any column of it.

Example : I'm creating a dimension on the first columns and grouping on the value of the last column, say it is `A-20, B-42, C-50, D-20.`. Now my group contains that values and variable.

But i'm looking to create a dimension combining 2-3 columns.

Example:

```
A,AA,20
A,AB,10
A,AC,30
A,AD,80
B,BA,30
B,BB,40
B,BC,50
B,BD,90
C,CA,70
C,CB,20
C,CC,10
C,CD,80
D,DA,30
D,DB,40
D,DC,60
D,DD,80
```

Is it possible to create a dimension on multiple columns like that?

If so please help me.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3v68c/3/

Answer (score 2):

If you provide a JSFiddle or something similar I can provide you a working example. But the answer is yes, you can define a dimension based on as many columns as you want. You just need to have a delimiter that isn't used in any of the values. Let's say you have columns a, b, and c and you're going to use delimiter ',' . Then you:

```
var xfilter = crossfilter(data); 
var multidimension = xfilter.dimension(function (d) {   
  return d.a + ',' + d.b + ',' + d.c;
});
```

Comment: Hey user3206082, I know you asked me to take a look at this (based on our previous thread) but Ethan has pointed you in the right direction.  If you are building a DC chart with the data, you might can make sure that your group has each field broken out separately as well.  In other words, use concatenation to define a dimension on many columns and then include the actual values for those columns in the group.

Comment: @Ethan To avoid the delimiter limitation you can define the dimension as an array, e.g. return [d.a,d.b,d.c];

Comment: @SimonGiles I think that's usually true, but IIRC what happens within Crossfilter is that the array is coerced using .toString(), so internally in Crossfilter it's actually treated as a comma-delimited string. I've heard some stories of things going wrong during this conversion so I don't tell other people do use arrays, but I secretly use them myself ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I created a jsfiddle for this at http://jsfiddle.net/djmartin_umich/7R9wd/.  It could use some cleaning up but it gets the point across.

1) Create your dimension with the concatenated fields (like Ethan suggested).  I created a new dimension because you probably want your graph to use the date only dimension.  In this case I converted the date to a string before concatenating.

```
 var dateLableDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return parseDate(d3.time.day.floor(d.date)) + " - " + d.label });
```

2) Store the actual date and label as part of the grouping method:

```
var dateDimTotal = dateDim.group().reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial);

    function reduceAdd(p, v) {
        p.date = parseDate(d3.time.day.floor(v.date));
        p.label = v.label;
        ++p.count;
        p.total += v.value;
        if (p.count == 0) {
            p.average = 0;
        } else {
            p.average = p.total / p.count;
        };
        return p;
    }
```

3) Refer to those fields in your dataTable (or dynaTable):

```
var datatable = $('.table').dataTable({
        "aaData" : dateDimTotal.top(Infinity),
        "bDestroy": true,
        "aoColumns": [
            { "mData": function(d) { return d.value.label; }, "sDefaultContent": ""},                
            { "mData": function(d) { return d.value.date; }, "sDefaultContent": ""},
            { "mData": function(d) { return d.value.count; }, "sDefaultContent": ""},
            { "mData": function(d) { return d.value.average; }, "sDefaultContent": ""}
        ]
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a single dimension directly in dc.js as an array of multiple key fields, if you look at the simple specific chart example for a series chart on dc.js Github you can see how this is done.